# Error while running storm topology in local mode:

Tags: yaml, apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

This is the error I have been facing while trying to implement the storm topology in local mode in storm 0.9.4 version.

```
Caused by: expected '<document start>', but found BlockMappingStart
 in 'reader', line 24, column 1:
    storm.zookeeper.port: 2181
    ^

    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl$ParseDocumentStart.produce(ParserImpl.java:225)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.peekEvent(ParserImpl.java:158)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.checkEvent(ParserImpl.java:143)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.getSingleNode(Composer.java:108)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.getSingleData(BaseConstructor.java:120)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.loadFromReader(Yaml.java:481)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.load(Yaml.java:424)
    at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.findAndReadConfigFile(Utils.java:141)
    at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.readStormConfig(Utils.java:188)
    at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.<clinit>(Utils.java:71)
    ... 100 more
```

Following is my storm.yaml file in /conf folder:

```
--- 
java.library.path: /usr/local/lib
nimbus.childopts: "-Xmx512m"
nimbus.host: localhost
storm.local.dir: /var/stormtmp
storm.zookeeper.port: 2181
storm.zookeeper.servers: 
  - localhost
supervisor.childopts: "-Xmx256m"
supervisor.slots.ports: 
  - 6700
  - 6701
  - 6702
  - 6703
worker.childopts: "-Xmx768m"
```

Comment: Looks like a problem with snakeyaml, that file parses fine for me in Ruby. What version are you using?

Comment: I tried making few changes with version of Ruby, I'm still not sure of the problem.  Do I need to change version of snakeyaml as well or do I need to change get the latest version of Ruby?

Comment: Solved the issue. I had some .storm folder as well in my root, which I had created during some sort of testing, the storm.yaml file saved in here was causing all the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

There has been some problem with your `yaml` files. And storm is not able to parse it. Make sure the file is not corrupted or rightly configured.

You can [try this online validator](http://www.yamllint.com/)

**EDIT**:

try to change :

```
    nimbus.host: localhost
```

to

```
    nimbus.host: "localhost"
```

And

```
    storm.local.dir: /var/stormtmp
```

to

```
    storm.local.dir: "/var/stormtmp"
```

And

```
    storm.zookeeper.servers: 
       - localhost
```

to

```
    storm.zookeeper.servers: 
      - "localhost"
```

Note the double quote around the values specified. 
[sample config for storm](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/conf/defaults.yaml)

Comment: No, I already had my  .yaml file validated. This could be an issue with Ruby as suggested by someone in comments

Comment: @user3550694 check the update and see if it helps .. this must have been something with the config file being corrupted

Comment: Hi, I have resolved the issue. Please see the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, if you copy this into any YAML validator, it will show yaml content validated. But this is the parsing error in storm.yaml file only. Check whether you have any unwanted tabspace or space in file.
Try to remove all tab or space and rewrite. Then it should work fine. You can also validate your yaml file on YAMLLint or http://instantyaml.appspot.com/ .

Also check storm.yaml file in ~/.storm folder. both files should be same and correct.

Comment: I did copy the storm.yaml file into the validator, everything was fine there, and there wasn't any issue related to tab or spaces.